# Is it slower to select from another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I am standing in database A and what to select from database B by using:

```
B.table.column
```

Is this going to slow things down compared to if the table was in databse A where I am standing?

Comment: If they are on the same server, there should not be a drastic difference.  But you can time your queries on your system and test.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: They are on the same server, sorry forgot to mention that. Is it slower to select from a view?

Comment: Selecting from a different database will have a very small impact.  Security is checked when crossing database boundaries and this adds some overhead to the query.  A view is just a saved query.  I've never seen a measurable difference from executing a query directly versus create the query as a view and executing it.

Comment: @WesH: But if the view is made up from a complicated query with many joins and slow then simply selecting top 1000 from that view will be slow. This might be the reason I think...

Comment: @David - If the query returns quickly when executed, it will still return quickly when turned into a view.  A view is just a saved query promoted to object status so it can be referenced by name.  0 difference in performance.  It will generate the same execution plan, use the same indexes and have the same problem as the original query.